# How does particle-particle interactions affect superfluids?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, bose-einstein-condensate, superfluidity, quantum-statistics

Ive read that London approach of superfluidity was wrong because he took them as non-interacting bose gas molecules and got incorrect temperature dependence for density, but also one can take superfluid phenomena to similar to **BEC**, so what is the correct explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Superfluidity is an interacting effect, so interactions play a pretty important role.

Bose-Einstein condensation, strictly speaking, is a non-interacting effect: the transition is driven purely by quantum statistics and not by interactions.

The superfluid critical velocity $v_c$ depends on the interaction strength $g$, and is hence $0$ for a (non-interacting) BEC. So if you really want to reconcile the two phenomena you could say that a BEC is a "boring" superfluid. But you can have superfluid states *without* BEC, e.g. the [BKT phase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosterlitz%E2%80%93Thouless_transition) in two dimensions where BEC is forbidden.

(A BEC is observed to "survive" repulsive interactions, it just sees a shift in its transition temperature, and a larger number of non-condensed atoms through [quantum depletion](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.01867)).

Comment: If not BEC then what is the true explanation for formation of a superfluid?

Comment: That the dispersion relation ($E$ vs $k$ curve) changes shape so that the velocity $v \propto \partial E/ \partial k$ does not go below a finite value $v_c$ at some $k$. For non-interacting fluids, the single particle dispersion relation is $E \propto k^2$, so the velocity will be $0$ at $k=0$. Interactions ($g$) will add a term in front of it so that $E \propto g k + k^2$ so that the velocity cannot drop below $g$, which is the suprefluid velocity.

Comment: Does it have to do something with the roton minima in the dispersion curve?

Comment: @SHIN101 Yes for very strong interactions at some $k$ the dispersion relation will have a parabolic minimum which is the roton.

Comment: any good references ??

Comment: [For an introduction](https://global.oup.com/ukhe/product/superconductivity-superfluids-and-condensates-9780198507567?cc=us&lang=en&)